# JQuery UI Autocomplete, hide div when more chars are typed in the input field

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input field populated with JQuery UI Autocomplete. The aim is to check that the value is **not** already present in the database.

When the selection is present, a #warning div is shown :

```
$("#item").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON(
          "search.php",
          { term:request.term, type:'item' }, 
          response
      );
   },
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#warning").show();
      $("#item").html('');
   }
```

I would like the #warning div to be hidden when the user selects an entry but adds some characters.

I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply adding a hide() function when autocomplete is called:

```
$("#item").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON(
          "search.php",
          { term:request.term, type:'item' }, 
          response
      );
      $("#warning").hide();
   },
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {
      $("#warning").show();
      $("#item").html('');
   }
```